# Validação de XML no Cadprev

Tags: xml

Preciso urgentemente validar um xml no sistema do Cadprev, mas não consigo encontrar o problema nele que faz aparecer a mensagem:" o arquivo escolhido não está no formato especificado pelo XML schema do demonstrativo". Gostaria de dicas de como tornar validavel esse xml

http://pasted.co/36d08b57  -  xml gerado
http://pasted.co/720d69a7  - php gerador

Comment: Preciso de mais informacoes sobre o que significa tornar validavel. Voce escreveu um programa que recebe um XML e agora quer validar ele?

Comment: Exatamente isso amigo, eu tenho um código em php que gera esse XML, agora eu preciso validar esse XML nesse formato de schema que parece ser o padrão, mas eu não sei como faço isso

Comment: apresente o esquema, o código que gera o seu xml e o xml gerado pelo seu código

Comment: eu editei lá, desculpa